# Select where max MySQL

Tags: mysql, max, sql-order-by, where-clause

Help, please make SQL select to database. There are such data.

#### My table is:

```
id  news_id  season  seria   date_update
---|------|---------|-----|--------------------
1  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 16:38:10
2  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 17:38:10
5  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 16:38:10
3  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 16:38:10
4  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 16:38:10
6  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 16:38:10
7  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 16:38:10
8  | 1    | 1       | 25  | 2017-04-23 18:42:00
```

Need to get all cells grouped by max season and seria and date and sorted by date_update DESC.

In result I need next rows

```
id  news_id  season  seria   date_update
---|------|---------|-----|--------------------
8  | 1    | 1       | 25  | 2017-04-23 18:42:00
2  | 4    | 1       | 7   | 2017-04-14 17:38:10
```

Because these rows have the highest season and seria and date_update per One news_id. i.e I need to select data which have highest season and seria and date_update grouped by news_id and also sorted by date_update DESC

I tried so, but the data is not always correct, and it does not always for some reason cover all the cells that fit the condition.

```
SELECT serial.* 
FROM serial as serial 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(season) AS maxseason, MAX(seria) AS maxseria FROM serial GROUP BY news_id) as one_serial 
ON serial.id = one_serial.id 
WHERE serial.season = one_serial.maxseason AND serial.seria = one_serial.maxseria 
ORDER BY serial.date_update
```

Please, help. Thanks.

Comment: Say you have two records for a news_id. One with season 1 and seria 2. Another with season 2 and seria 1. So maximum season is 2 and maximum seria is 2. But there is no record for season 2 and seria 2. So you don't want to show any result row for this news_id?

Comment: oh, i understood the problem, thank you. Make you help compose request for sql? Maybe you know a better option than i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification is unclear.

But we do know that the **`GROUP BY news_id`** clause is going collapse all of the rows with a common value of `news_id` into a single row. (Other databases would throw an error with this syntax; we can get MySQL to throw a similar error if we include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `sql_mode`.)

My suggestion would be to remove the **`GROUP BY news_id`** clause from the end of the query.

But that's just a guess. It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

**EDIT**

```
 SELECT t.* 
   FROM ( 
          SELECT r.news_id
               , r.season
               , r.seria
               , MAX(r.date_update) AS max_date_update
            FROM ( 
                   SELECT p.news_id
                        , p.season
                        , MAX(p.seria) AS max_seria
                     FROM ( 
                            SELECT n.news_id
                                 , MAX(n.season) AS max_season
                              FROM serial n 
                             GROUP BY n.news_id
                          ) o
                     JOIN serial p
                       ON p.news_id = o.news_id
                      AND p.season  = o.max_season
                 ) q
            JOIN serial r
              ON r.news_id = q.news_id
             AND r.season  = q.season
             AND r.seria   = q.max_seria
         ) s
    JOIN serial t      
      ON t.news_id     = s.news_id
     AND t.season      = s.season
     AND t.seria       = s.seria
     AND t.date_update = s.max_date_update
   GROUP BY t.news_id
   ORDER BY t.news_id
```

Or, an alternate approach making use of MySQL user-defined variables...

```
 SELECT s.id
      , s.season
      , s.seria
      , s.date_update 
   FROM ( 
          SELECT IF(q.news_id = @p_news_id,0,1) AS is_max
               , q.id
               , @p_news_id := q.news_id AS news_id
               , q.season
               , q.seria
               , q.date_update
            FROM ( SELECT @p_news_id := NULL ) r
           CROSS
            JOIN serial q
           ORDER
              BY q.news_id     DESC
               , q.season      DESC
               , q.seria       DESC
               , q.date_update DESC
        ) s
  WHERE s.is_max
  ORDER BY s.news_id
```

Comment: I need to get all the cells with the highest season and seria sorted by date_update DESC and all this GROUP BY news_id (I.e not to repeat value from news_id ). If i remove GROUP BY, it's get me all row per news_id

Comment: @SakurasouCat: Consider providing *example data* and the *expected result* to clarify the specification. Because your description is very unclear, and leaves us guessing what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: i have next data - https://prnt.sc/few90a and i need get next result https://prnt.sc/few8js because this rows have highest season and seria and date_update per One news_id. I.e i need to select data wich have highest season and seria and date_update grouped by news_id and also sorted by date_update DESC

Comment: Please provide additional information as an *edit* to the original *question*, not as a comment on the answer. (And note that images are a lazy *horrible* way to provide example data and expected results.)

Comment: Thank you! Alternative select working excellent! First query not return data, empty result. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

The subquery selects the maximum `season` and the maximum `seria` per `news_id`. How many records exist for the `news_id` that match both the maximum `season` and the maximum `seria` we don't know. It can be, one or two or thousand or zero.

So with the join you get an unknown number of records per `news_id`. Then you group by `news_id`. This gets you one result row per `news_id`. How then can you select `serial.*`? `*` means all columns from a row, but which row,when there can be many for a `news_id`? MySQL usually picks values arbitrarily in this case (usually all from the same row, but even that is not guaranteed). So you end up with random rows which you order by `date_update`.

This doesn't make much sense. So the question is: what do you really want to achieve? Maybe my explanation suffices and you are able now to fix your query yourself.

Comment: Senk for comment, You explained well, but I do not have enough knowledge to fix it myself.

Comment: And I have no knowledge about what you are trying to achieve. Edit your request, explain what you want to do, show some sample data and expected result, so we understand what you are after.

Comment: Okay, i understood. i did something like this

`SELECT serial.* FROM serial as serial INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(season) AS maxseason, MAX(seria) AS maxseria FROM serial GROUP BY news_id) as one_serial ON serial.id = one_serial.id WHERE serial.season = one_serial.maxseason AND serial.seria = one_serial.maxseria ORDER BY serial.date_update DESC`

But return data not correct https://prnt.sc/fev7b6 I have row with big data than in row with id 1 for news_id 4

Comment: I need to get all the cells with the highest season and seria sorted by date_update DESC and all this GROUP BY news_id (I.e not to repeat value from news_id )

Comment: Do you or don't you want exactly one result row per news_id? If you do, then which of the rows do you want to show when there are several with the highest season and seria?

Comment: Yes, i want to show all rows with highest season and seria sorted by date DESC per news_id. And i don't know how to do it :c

Comment: No. I am asking: Do you want to show *all* rows with highest season and seria for a news_id? OR do you want to show only *one* such row for a news_id?

Comment: one such row for a news_id

Comment: And which???? In your screen shot there are seven rows for news_id 4 that *all* have the maximum season 1 and maximum seria 7. So which of these rows do you want to show?

Comment: and max date. In screen we have seven rows for news_id 4 but in row with id 2 have highest date_update than other rows. If date, seria and season are equal everywhere get one any row per news_id